# No matter what I do, sublime text 2 gives me that same error message.?

Tags: java, python, sublimetext2

I'm writing python code in ST2, even the simplist code such like print "stackoverflow" will not work. I tried to write Java code, same thing happened.

No matter what i write, no matter which script i write, ST2 gives me this:

```
javac: invalid flag: /Users/air/Desktop/test.py
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

What should i do? I googled it, and i failed to find a solution. There's a post said it's the problem of Java JDK, i tried to install it, nothing changed.

Thank you so much for solving this! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **`Tools -> Build System`** and select **`Python`**. You should now be able to go to your Python script, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, and see the results in the build panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to syntax python in ST2. Apparently, you are on some sort of plugin that should validate java code, and tries to validate python code.
Check menu in ST2: View->Syntax->python

Comment: nope, that didn't work... still, thanks for the answer.